# XML Deserialization (issues)

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, serialization, xml-serialization

I am having some trouble casting to the B type after deserializing XML.

For eg.

```
class Base
class A: Base
class B: A
```

I can deserialize to A, but cannot cast to B.

Is it possible to deserialize to A and then cast to B?

Answer (score 2):

You say you are having difficulty casting to the base-type, but B is not the base-type: it is a sub-type. If that cast fails, it means the deserialization returned an A but not a B. for the serializer to return a B, it must be obvious in the data that it **is** a B, so basically: you must have serialized a B.